# Using fifo to read and write in a walkietalkie like way

Tags: c

For one of my assignments I am given 2 .c programs and I need to complete a third program which makes the first 2 work. The first program runs if the user enters a name and a name for a file to record the conversation being had in the output file . While the user is not "speaking" the second program is a "listening" program that waits for another user to input something.

I'm having trouble getting the output file to get the users input. It does record to the output file but it does more than once. I'm also having trouble getting the output to show on the other terminal running the same program.

1. Program 1 . wt.c

The first program begins by checking to see if arguments "user" "fifo" and "recording" are entered as arguments in command. Then if so, it creates a text document "recording" in my directory which with my speak program captures the messages being sent between the 2 programs operating the fifo.

It then creates a location in tmp for the fifo. `/tmp/argv[2]/.fifo`

It then populates a list of arguments to be passed into the second program called ./listen.

```
  args[0]="./listen";
  args[1]=user;
  args[2]=myfifo;
  args[3]=myrecording;
  args[4]=NULL;
```

It then ends the program by replacing in memory using execvp, the wt program with the listen program and passes the args listed into the second program /.listen

2. Program 2 - .listen

program starts with setting the old arguments as user, myfifo, myrecording.
It then populates another list of arguments to be passed into my program that I need to pass in and use in the program I need to write - ".speak".

```
 args[0]="./speak";
 args[1]=user         //argv[1];
 args[2]=myfifo       //argv[2];
 args[3]=myrecording  //argv[3];
 args[4]=NULL;
```

- first uncertainty

it then uses sigaction to alter control-\ - (not entirely sure how this works so if someone could explain this id appreciate it. it seems to use the execvp "tospeak" function created which takes in the new arguments just listed above

```
mysignal.sa_handler=tospeak;
mysignal.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER |SA_RESETHAND ;
sigaction(SIGQUIT, &mysignal, NULL);
```

starts a while loop which tells the user that it's "reading any messages being sent from other program running this fifo.
next it says to press control-\ to send a message to the other person.

- second uncertainty

it then creates a fifo with permissions 0660, opens the fifo as read only called fdr which im assuming means file descriptor?, reads the fifo `read(fdr, message, 80)`(I get the message and length of 80 but unsure about how the `int fdr` works - does it look and see how big the file is?)

prints the message to the user and then closes the read only fifo request.

it then opens the recording in append mode and appends the message read.

3. My program - .speak

To my understanding once Control-\ is pressed in the listen program, it switches over to the speak program.

To get this started, I believe I need to populate a new set of arguments to pass back into the .listen program. I also believe I need to make a fifo in write mode to have the listening program iterate was was said.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


char message[80];
char *theargs[5];
char *myfifo;
char *myrecording;
char *user;
FILE *recorded;
struct sigaction mysignal;
int fd;


//if ctrlc or ctrlz tell user they are disabled during speaking
//reprompt user to send message and hit enter
void ctrlc()
{
    printf ("\nControl c disabled while speaking\n");
    printf ("enter ur message. (hit [Enter] to continue):\n");      

}
void ctrlz()
{
    printf ("\nControl z disabled while speaking\n");
    printf ("enter ur message. (hit [Enter] to continue):\n");  

}

void tospeak()
{
    execvp(theargs[0], theargs);
}

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, ctrlc);
    signal(SIGTSTP, ctrlz);

    user = argv[1];
    myfifo = argv[2];
    myrecording = argv[3];

    theargs[0] = "./listen";
    theargs[1] = user;
    theargs[2] = myfifo;
    theargs[3] = myrecording;
    theargs[4] = NULL;

    mysignal.sa_handler=tospeak;
    mysignal.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER |SA_RESETHAND ;
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &mysignal, NULL);

    
    while (1)
    {
        printf ("\nenter ur message. (hit [Enter] to send message):\n");

        
        fd = open(myfifo,O_WRONLY);
        fgets(message, 80, stdin);
        write(fd, message, strlen(message)+1);
        close(fd);

        recorded = fopen(myrecording, "a");
        fprintf(recorded, "%s\n", message);
        fclose(recorded);
        printf("message sent: %s\n", message);

        execvp(theargs[0], theargs);

    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Strong advice to read Stevens. Possibly daily ... BTW:: signal handlers should **not** use printf() kind of fiunctions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with that. What is Stevens?

Comment: It is a book (APUE). From 1992, but still mostly valid.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment about `printf`: see [`signal-safety(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for an outline on *async-signal-safe* functions. `printf` is not included in the list.

Comment: @Oka can you elaborate on this further. My ctlz and ctlc functions?

Comment: Basically, to be safe, instead of `printf`, you should use equivalent calls to `write` in your signal handlers. This is surely an aside to your main issues here, though.

Comment: If we're recommending Steven's - APUE, why not 3ed-2013? @wildplasser

Comment: According to my partner, the code works fine on his driver. It was very spotty on mine. VSCode wasn't outputting the all of the messages or messages would be duplicated. Going to try on someone else's computer and see for myself. Thanks for the help so far